# How to implement for-loops in Matlab Function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, for-loop, simulink

I have a piece of code that works perfectly when run from the command line, but when it is run inside of a Matlab function block in my Simulink simulation, I get a matrix dimensioning error.

Using the debugger, I have figured out that the for-loop is behaving differently from how I expect and I'm not sure how to fix it without major re-writes to someone else's code.

Here is the snippet of code that is causing problems.

```
for k=input
        idx=4+2*(i-1)+1;
        yhat=yhat+th(idx)*cos(k.*(2.*pi.*60.*t+th(1).*t))+th(idx+1)*sin(k*(2*pi*60*t+th(1)*t));
end
```

Normally, k would take on each value from 2 to 13 and this would run as one would expect a for loop to run.  For some reason, when I set a breakpoint on the `yhat` line, I am finding that k is the vector `[2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13]`, which is the transpose of what I expect `input` to be.  Does anyone know what is going on that would make this code run differently in the Matlab Function block or how to fix it?

Comment: Where do you define the input variable?

Answer (score 0):

**facepalm**, I figured it out right after posting the question.  Apparently Simulink `Constant` blocks will output a column vector even when supplied with a row vector.

For loops iterate over the column of the supplied vector, so

```
for ii = [1 2; 3 4]
    ii
end
```

outputs `[1;3]` `[2;4]` for example.  Because the constant block was supplying my input as a column vector, this led to the for loop iterating over the 1 column.  Transposing the vector fixed the issue.